# How to make an animation for the changing variables and start it by clicking a button (in p5.js)

Tags: javascript, html, p5.js

I have  a problem that I need use p5.js to draw a ball projecting in a parabola track,and there are two input that I can type the degree of between the bottom of the canvas and the parabola track (or you can call Elevation angle) and the initial speed of the ball. After typing in these two information, I can push the "project button" to make the ball start moving on the track that I just set, and when the ball drop on the button of the canvas which means the projection is over, I also need a button to clear the canvas to the initial situation and I can change the degree and initial speed to have a new projection.It is also recommended to show the vertical and horizontal distance from the left and the bottom of the canvas every 0.5 seconds. Please somebody help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Could you post some code?

Comment: Well maybe I can make an animation that the ball is just moving in a stationary parabola track and start immediately when I open it, but the real problem is that there are two variable that I need to change , and also the animation should start when the button is pressed, which  are the problems that I cannot figure out for days.